# Inserting JSON data into Postgresql from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: postgresql, jenkins-pipeline, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert JSON data into my database from Jenkins pipeline, unfortunately I have problem with proper format.
My query looks like that:

```
def insertQuery = """
                  INSERT INTO public.metrics(pr, info) VALUES ('KP-1111', '{"key": "value"}');
                  """
```

and later:

```
  sh """
     PGPASSWORD="${dbPassword}" psql -h ${dbHost} -p ${dbPort} -d ${dbName} -U ${dbUser} -c "${insertQuery}" -w
     """
```

Error I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 2: ... INTO public.metrics(pr, info) VALUES ('KP-1111', '{key: val...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Token "key" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {key...
```

I tried to escape signs, move JSON into variable instead of hardcode in query. Is there any other option I can insert this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quietly mismatched quotes. The `query` string has `key` and `value` surrounded in double quotes, then the `sh` again surrounds the entire `query` in double quotes, so your `-c "${insertQuery}"` ends up evaluated to:

```sh
-c "INSERT INTO public.metrics(pr, info) VALUES ('KP-1111', '{"key": "value"}');"
```

which terminates the string at the double quote before `key`, concatenates it with `key`, reopens quoted string and continues up until `value` and does the same, cutting it up like this:

```
"INSERT INTO public.metrics(pr, info) VALUES ('KP-1111', '{"
key
": "
value
"}');"
```

So you end up losing those double quotes entirely. Which is why you can see the error message without them around `key` and `value`:

```sql
"INSERT INTO public.metrics(pr, info) VALUES ('KP-1111', '{key: value}');"
```

You can escape the quotes with `\` to avoid them terminating the string in your `sh`:

```sh
def insertQuery = """
                  INSERT INTO public.metrics(pr, info) VALUES ('KP-1111', '{\\"key\\": \\"value\\"}');
                  """
```

Comment: I was escaping like this, didn't help

Comment: You're right, the escaping needs to be doubled to make it into the second string. Otherwise the first one already uses up the backslashes. See the update.

Comment: Yeah, double escaping works, thanks! If I want to move this JSON into variable, should I keep it in `'singlequote'` or `"""multiline"""`?

Comment: Since the `json` literal shouldn't typically use single quotes inside it, it shouldn't matter but remember to keep the single quotes in your `insert...values()` around where you inject the variable, for PostgreSQL to understand that as a `text` literal matching the column `json` type input format. You might want to look into ways to bind or auto-escape, otherwise you might run into problems whenever the actual keys and values happen to contain some sort of quotes that could interfere with yours, not to mention SQL injection risks.